# I am facing a problem whenever try to I delete a record

Tags: vb.net, basic

```
Private Sub DeleteButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DeleteButton.Click
        ' Delete

        Try

            If MessageBox.Show("Do you want to permanently delete the selected record?",
                               "Delete Data", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                                MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) =
                                Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then

                Pass_TableBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()

                Pass_TableBindingSource.EndEdit()
                Pass_TableTableAdapter.Update(Pass_DBDataSet.pass_Table)

                RefreshData()

                MessageBox.Show("The record has been deleted successfully.",
            "Data Deleted Successfully", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Else
                Return '' Exit Sub
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception

            MessageBox.Show("Delete Data Failed: " & ex.Message.ToString(),
                            "Delete Data Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

        End Try
    End Sub
```

**This is the code that I used to delete a record. I am developing this software in Visual Studio 2019 (16.5.3)**

```
connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\pass_DB\pass_DB.mdb;Persist Security Info=True"
```

Here is the error I got.
[***Error***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruoE0.png)

Comment: I want to write Visual Basic but 'Stack Overflow' do not accept this tag, so I just wrote basic. The programming language I used is Visual Basic. I have used Microsoft Access 2019 my database extension is *.mdb.

Comment: The basic tag is okay, as this is basic, but I've added the dot net tag since you don't specifiy which flavor of dot net you're using.

Comment: This ***is*** BASIC.  VB.NET is a dialect of BASIC (though *very, very different* from early dialects), and it's generally the only dialect that should be taken seriously in this day and age.  You could also think of BASIC as a family of languages, wherein VB.NET is the only modern member, but either way, VB.NET *is* a type of BASIC.

Comment: (Sometimes you might have to deal with VB6/VBA, but VB.NET's a lot better and more modern for general-purpose programming.)

Comment: @TusharChaurasia In .NET, without extra third-party libraries or special add-ons or anything, there are at least a couple of ways of interacting with databases.  The one you're using (working directly with SQL data / table adapters and such) is less common, I think, and I haven't personally worked with it in a while.  The best I recall, you need to take one of the objects you're using (either the table adapter, SQL data adapter, or something else related) and give it a command to execute for deleting records.

Comment: So I've forgotten which type it is (again, this methodology is probably not used directly most of the time, and I haven't personally used it in years), but take the `DeleteCommand` property or whatever and set it to something like `"DELETE FROM [MyTable] WHERE <SomeCondition>"`.

Comment: Then when you refresh the data, it'll see the deleted records in your DataRow collection, and it'll run the delete command you supplied, to delete those records in the database.  The problem I think it's running into now is that it just hasn't been given a delete command to run yet, but it knows it needs one, because it sees those deleted records.  In the error message, when it says, "Update requires a valid...", it's not talking about the `UPDATE` command in SQL specifically, but about *updating* the state of the database.

Comment: I don't remember the details of this methodology clearly enough to post this as an answer, but am using the comments instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
Try
    BindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
    BindingSource.EndEdit()
    TableAdapter.Update(DataSet.database)
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
End Try
```